# Select entire row from 2d object[] where first column value matches

Tags: linq

I have a 2D object array containing something like this:

```
Filename | "filename.txt" | 1
Path     | "C:\temp\"     | 2
Date     | 16/06/2015     | 3
```

I'd like to extract from this array the row which matches a given header, where the header is the value of the first column. For example, given 'Path', I'd like to be given:

```
Path | "C:\temp\"  | 2
```

I'm currently looping through to find the correct row number, then looping through that row to extract it. I'm pretty sure that using linq could make this look a bit nicer but I've had very little use in it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more info about your data structure? From your self-written tables it's hard to deduce how your data is stored in your objects.

Comment: Yep - sorry. The array is declared just as an object. It's containing data from excel, so can end up with a lot of different things in it. In the example above, it ends up being a 2D array of objects, but the first column will always be a string

Comment: Is it a rectangular array (`[,]`) or a jagged array (`[][]`).  Extracting columns from a jagged array in C# is much easier than a rectangular array.

Comment: It's a rectangular array

Comment: Linq won't help on rectangular arrays since they can't enumerate columns or rows - only cells.  Your `for` loop may be the most efficient.

Comment: You may be better off creating an 1-D array (or dictionary) of objects rather than a 2-D array.

Comment: Ok, yes, that's possibly a good direction - I'll give it a go or stick with what I have. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a jagged array, it's fairly straightforward:

```
object[][] jagged = { new object[]  {"Filename", "filename.txt", 1},
                      new object[] {"Path", @"C:\Temp", 2},
                      new object[] {"Date", new DateTime(2015,6,16), 3}};

var q = from j in jagged
        where (j[0] as string) == "Path"
        select j;

var row = q.FirstOrDefault();
// row is an object[3] array
```

in fact, that can be reduced to just:

```
var row = jagged.FirstOrDefault(j =>(j[0] as string) == "Path");
```

Howeverf, if you are using a rectangluar array, it get much uglier.  Rectangular arrays have no concept of "rows" or "columns", just cells, so you'd need to build a new array:

```
object[,] rect = { { "Filename", "filename.txt", 1},
                    {"Path", @"C:\Temp", 2},
                    {"Date", new DateTime(2015,6,16), 3}};

var result = new object[rect.GetLength(1)];

for(int i = rect.GetLowerBound(0); i <= rect.GetUpperBound(0); ++i)
{
    if (rect[i, rect.GetLowerBound(1)] as string == "Path")
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rect.GetLength(1); ++j)
            result[j] = rect[i, rect.GetLowerBound(1) + j];
        break;
    }
}
```